# Running BlackBerry application automatically directly after installation

Tags: blackberry, installation, ota

I have written an application that injects some menu items in other BlackBerry applications (for example a "bookmark this page" menu item in the BlackBerry browser). I have configured the application to be run automatically at startup (of the device) so when the device starts, the menu items are installed in the other applications.

However, I would also like to have my application started directly after installation (via OTA), so the menu items are directly available to the user. Is there a way to accomplish this without having the user to reboot the device or manually start the application after installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Autostart applications should run
>   automatically after they have been
>   installed.  What could have happened
>   is the application tried to autostart,
>   but didn't have the permissions to do
>   what it wanted and failed with a
>   ControlledAccessException.  Often this
>   can be seen as the application failing
>   to start, but in fact it did start but
>   just wasn't allowed to do what it
>   tried to do.
>
> Check the event log on the BlackBerry
>   (alt+lglg).  You should see an entry
>   for your application being started
>   after it was installed.
>
> Mark Sohm BlackBerry Development
>   Advisor www.BlackBerryDeveloper.com

[BB Support Community Forums :Can we automatically run the application after install](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&view=by_date_ascending&message.id=21626#M21626)

Comment: +1, FTR, when I tried ALT+lglg it worked from the home screen, NOT from inside my application.